# How to use ThreadPoolExecutor in python for Parallelization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am unable to run **ThreadPoolExecutor** in python & openCV

this is my code

```
def main(video_path,visualization,count):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error opening video stream or file")

    while cap.isOpened():

        count = count + 1

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        raw_frame = None
        if ret:
            raw_frame = frame.copy()
        if ret:
            frame = resize_img(frame, 50)
            if count % FREQUENCY == 0:
                face_locations = hogFaceDetector(frame, 0)

                if len(face_locations) > 0:
                    sorted_detections_distances = calculate_face_distance(face_locations, frame, faces_encodings)

                    if sorted_detections_distances[0][1] < TOLERANCE_THRES:
                        print(str(sorted_detections_distances[0][0]))


                    if visualization == True:

                        for faceRect in face_locations:
                            x1 = faceRect.left()
                            y1 = faceRect.top()
                            x2 = faceRect.right()
                            y2 = faceRect.bottom()

                            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y2), (x1, y1), (0, 0, 255), 4)
                            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 4)
                            cv2.line(frame, (x2, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 4)
                            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y1), (0, 0, 255), 4)
                            cv2.putText(frame, str(sorted_detections_distances[0][0]), (x1, y1),
                                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,
                                        (255, 0, 0), 3)


                            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

            if visualization == True:
                cv2.imshow('raw_frame', raw_frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    visualization = False
    count = 0

    with open('faces_encodings.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        faces_encodings = pickle.load(handle)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        process1 = executor.submit(main, ("stock.mp4",visualization,count))
        process2 = executor.submit(main, ("stock2.mp4",visualization,count))
        process3 = executor.submit(main, ("stock3.mp4",visualization,count))
```

I was able to attain some level of multi-processing using old multi-processing technique

**this was working**

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=("stock.mp4",visualization,count))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=("stock2.mp4",visualization,count))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=("stock3.mp4",visualization,count))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

But when I am running this same using **ThreadPoolExecutor** nothing is getting run programs finishes off instantly without throwing any error

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)?  There are several ways to wait for all submitted tasks to finish. 
 One is `for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):` which will loop once per completed task.  Also, not sure why you're passing `count` as an argument to `main()` if it will be 0 every time.

Comment: Is it on MacOs?